# Firebug Lite for Chrome spoils hover effect and mouseover event

Tags: css, google-chrome, hover, firebug, firebug-lite

I've got a weird issue: when using [Firebug Lite for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/firebug-lite-for-google-c/bmagokdooijbeehmkpknfglimnifench), sometimes hover does not work.

What I've got: a `div` like this:

```
<div class="editWindow">
    <ul>
        <li id="edCha" onclick="channels.add()">
            Редактировать канал
        </li>
        <li id="delCha" onclick="channels.chanLink()">
            Подключить клиента
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and this CSS:

```css
.editWindow li:hover, .chooseAction li:hover {
    background: #369;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

It all looks like this, when I first open the page and then activate Firebug:

[image: editWindow with hover after page load]

But if I first activate Firebug and then open this page, hover just doesn't work. I see no error in the Firebug console, and no hover effect, like this (the mouse pointer is there, believe me):

[image: editWindow missing hover effect with Firebug activated]

I've got this issue only in Chrome (Firefox works well), both on Win7 and on Linux (Mint 14).

What can the cause be? I'm confused.

#### edit

When using `Force element state -> :hover` in the dev-tools menu, the hover style works.

#### edit 2

I've added `onmouseover="alert('test');"` to one of these `li` elements. In the second case, `alert` is not even being called!

Comment: I have experienced that sometimes , hover doesn't work when the developer console is open in chrome. I am not saying that this will solve your problem,just want to know if there's any work around / reason for it.

Comment: The focus might be on Firebug, not the page.

Comment: @Rory O'Kane, thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 3):

This might be not what you actually need, but if you use usual Chrome *Developer Tools* instead of Firebug for Chtome you can force an element to have a certain state. Just right-click on element in elements tree and choose any state in *Force Element State* menu item. Very useful for modifying CSS. IMHO it is better to use native tools in Chrome, albeit Firebug can be more useful.

Comment: Just used this, see my edit :) I don't use chrome firebug at all, but it's a bug and so I have to fix it.

Comment: Well, I guess Firebug is called this way for a good reason :P . Can't you just fallback to native Chrome Developer Tools to test this hover issue, and use Firebug for other stuff?

Comment: +1 for fireBug :) That's not me, some others in our company use it, and they want me to fix it. (This is not actually a site, it's our local web app)